# Pickup a Value from HTML after fetch react

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm working on a proyect and I'm trying to show only one value of a HTML after fetch it with react...
I think the problem is that I'm doing a innerHTML from that result and then a querySelector for the div I need to show..but I don't know how to show only that element, not the entire HTML.. One solution maybe It's use a `display none` on the rest, but I doubt about it...any help?
Thanks

Here it's my code:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'

function Test () {

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await fetch(https://myurl.com);

      const grid = document.querySelector('.grid')
      grid.innerHTML = result // -->  here insert all the html into grid section

      const txt = document.querySelector(".bys"); //-->  Here select the div I need to show

    };
 
    fetchData();
  });


  return(
    <section className="grid">
    </section>
  )
}



export default Test
```

And the HTML it's:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>la la la</title>
</head>

<body>
        <nav id="hdr" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 visible-xs" style="padding:0 8px !important">
                        <div class="col-xs-5 no-padding">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a href="login">Enter</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-1 col-sm-2 hidden-xs">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">&nbsp;</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-7 text-center hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right bys">
                            <li class="bys_txt">Oprion 1: </li>
                            <li class="bys_value">1.000</li>
                            <li class="bys_txt">Option 2</li>
                            <li class="bys_value">3.0232</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear0"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That's not how you're supposed to use React. You do not use querySelector or innerHTML. Please follow some tutorials before asking questions like this.

Comment: Mutating the DOM directly breaks React, so you shouldn't do that.

Comment: Using innerHTML on server data is unsafe and can cause XXS attack